# AsynStorage {"40":0,"_65":0,"_55":null,"_72":null} in React native

Tags: react-native

```
  async function addSessionId() {
          return await AsyncStorage.getItem("session_id", (err, result) => {
            console.warn(result);
            return result;
          });
        }
```

when i trying to store seesion id in Localstorage using AsynStorage in React native return {"40":0,"_65":0,"_55":null,"_72":null} value. how to getItem use in AsynStorage.

Answer (score 4):

Try this. Remember to make the function `async`

```
try {
  const value = await AsyncStorage.getItem('session_id')
  if (value !== null) {
    console.log(value)
  }
} catch (e) {
  console.error('No data', e)
}
```

https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/asyncstorage.html

Comment: i want return value

Comment: in that example, `value` is the return value?

Comment: config.headers["session_id"] = sessionId();

Comment: sessionId = async () => {
  try {
    const value = await AsyncStorage.getItem("session_id");
    if (value !== null) {
      console.warn(value); return value;
    }
  } catch (error) {
    console.warn("AsyncStorage Error: " + error.message);
  }
};

Comment: It's an async function, so you cannot do: `config.headers["session_id"] = sessionId()` without awaiting the function... `config.headers["session_id"] = await sessionId()`. Make sure the function you're using is also async though

Comment: when i use await sessionId()  i got error await is reserved word.

Comment: You need read about how `async` / `await` work. Maybe even looking first at how Promises work. In your case, as I said already, `Make sure the function you're using is also async though`...

Comment: const sessionId = async () => {
  alert("dfgd");
  try {
    let id = await AsyncStorage.getItem("session_id");
    alert(id);
    return id;
  } catch (error) {
    console.warn("AsyncStorage Error: " + error.message);
  }
};

Answer (score 2):

getItem returns promise. you need to call `then`

Use this :

```
    async function addSessionId() {
             let session
             await AsyncStorage.getItem('session_id').then(value => session = value); 
            return session

            }
```

Comment: i got same error {“40”:0,“_65”:0,“_55”:null,“_72”:null}

Comment: interceptors: {
    request: [
      (getState, config) => {
        async function addSessionId() {
          let session;
          await AsyncStorage.getItem("session_id").then(
            value => (session = value)
          );

Comment: console.warn(session);
          return session;
        }
      
        config.headers["session_id"] = addSessionId();
        console.warn(config.headers["session_id"]);
        
          
     
        return config;
      }

Answer (score 0):

No, for good return you need use this.setState() in your then()

Comment: example : if i need get the data in componentDidMount() (or useEffect())
for not return the result : `{"40":0,"_65":0,"_55":null,"_72":null}`

  `componentDidMount() {
    axios
      .post("url/api.....")
      .then(res => {
        this.setState({ data: res.data });
      })
      .catch(err => console.log(err));
  }`

and in my render i have my data !